# Extracting text from dropdown in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from dropdown using selenium and store it as a list.Any methods to do that using Selenium:
The HTML is as follows:

```html
<ul data-v-c71dad74="" data-dropdown-list="" class="list"><li data-v-c71dad74="" data-dropdown-item="09003" class="selected"> Hartford, CT </li><li data-v-c71dad74="" data-dropdown-item="09013" class=""> Tolland, CT </li></ul>
```

I tried using beautiful soup but the soup does not have the element itself.

```py
zipcode = '06042'
driver.get("https://plans.humana.com/?target=plans&kc=0805010007&zipcode="+zipcode)
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
time.sleep(5)

page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

filename = r'C:\RPA_Configuration\Nishant\page.html'

with open(filename, 'w') as file:
 file.write(str(soup.prettify()))
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, you tried using beautiful soup but the soup does not have the element itself because the element you're looking for gets loaded on the web page only after you click on the `Select county` dropdown.

Here is how you can solve this.

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()

zipcode = '06042'
driver.get("https://plans.humana.com/?target=plans&kc=0805010007&zipcode="+zipcode)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.input-wrapper')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.input-wrapper').click()
time.sleep(1)
page = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

filename = r'page.html'
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify())
```

`page.html`:

```html
<html data-whatinput="pointer" lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
  <link href="/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180"/>
  <link href="/site.webmanifest" rel="manifest"/>
  <meta content="#da532c" name="msapplication-TileColor"/>
  <meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color"/>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" data-role="gateway" data-vendor="fs" id="utag_56" src="//gateway.foresee.com/sites/humana/production/gateway.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_473" src="//solutions.invocacdn.com/js/invoca-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="https://www.everestjs.net/static/le/last-event-tag-latest.min.js">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_449" src="https://pixel.everesttech.net/rlsa/8564" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/humana/main/prod/utag.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script data-dtconfig="rid=RID_-369540585|rpid=1472886392|domain=humana.com|reportUrl=https://cagf-dt.humana.com:443/bf/d3610855-748f-4365-9bb1-f036451fac27|app=ec9bb5ce87255230|ssc=1|cors=1|featureHash=ICA27NQVfghjqrtux|msl=153600|srsr=25000|vcv=2|rdnt=1|uxrgce=1|bp=3|cuc=dd3lovee|srms=2,1,0,0%2Ftextarea%2Cinput%2Cselect%2Coption;0%2Fdatalist;0%2Fform%20button;0%2F%5Bdata-dtrum-input%5D;0%2F.data-dtrum-input;1%2F%5Edata%28%28%5C-.%2B%24%29%7C%24%29|mel=100000|dpvc=1|md=mdcc1=a#error-message,mdcc2=dutm_content,mdcc3=dutm_term,mdcc4=dutm_campaign,mdcc5=dutm_medium,mdcc6=dutm_source,mdcc7=bnavigator.userAgent,mdcc8=bdocument.referrer,mdcc9=bs.eVar1,mdcc10=bwindow.utag_data.page_name_no_spaces,mdcc11=bs.prop10,mdcc12=bwindow.utag_data.tealium_session_id,mdcc13=bs.eVar75,mdcc14=chum_refer_page_name,mdcc15=abody ^rb div:nth-child(3) ^rb header.sub-header ^rb div ^rb div.right-side ^rb div ^rb button ^rb span|ssv=4|lastModification=1683120029007|mdp=mdcc1|dtVersion=10259230221142207|tp=500,50,0,1|uxdcw=1500|agentUri=/ruxitagentjs_ICA27NQVfghjqrtux_10259230221142207.js" src="/ruxitagentjs_ICA27NQVfghjqrtux_10259230221142207.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="/js/mp_linkcode.js">
  </script>
  <script>
   MP.UrlLang='mp_js_current_lang';
      MP.SrcUrl=decodeURIComponent('mp_js_orgin_url');
      MP.oSite=decodeURIComponent('mp_js_origin_baseUrl');
      MP.tSite=decodeURIComponent('mp_js_translated_baseUrl');
      MP.init();
      var mp_langLink = function() {
          var langlinks = document.querySelectorAll('.langLink');
          for (var i = 0; i < langlinks.length; i++) {
              langlinks.item(i).onclick = function() {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  MP.init();
                  var lang = this.getAttribute('data-lang');
                  var url = this.getAttribute('data-href');
                  var tSite = MP.tSite.replace(/(https?:\/\/|\/?$)/g,'');
                  url = url.replace(/(https?:\/\/|\/?$)/g,'');
                  MP.switchLanguage(tSite.search(url)!=-1?MP.oSite:url, lang, true);
                  return false;
              }
          }
      };
      if(window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener('load',mp_langLink,false);
      }else if(window.attachEvent){
        window.attachEvent('onload',mp_langLink);
      }
  </script>
  <title>
   Humana
  </title>
  <script src="/config.js">
  </script>
  <script defer="defer" src="/chunk-vendors.8f9c2458ab95d76e.js" type="module">
  </script>
  <script defer="defer" src="/main.8f9c2458ab95d76e.js" type="module">
  </script>
  <link href="/css/main.d21f12a8.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script defer="defer" nomodule="" src="/chunk-vendors.8f9c2458ab95d76e.js">
  </script>
  <script defer="defer" nomodule="" src="/main.8f9c2458ab95d76e.js">
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .progress[data-v-cc6c5ab2]{-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);transform:rotate(-90deg)}
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
   .progress-container[data-v-f1691f2e]{stroke-width:2px}.progress-container .top[data-v-f1691f2e]{z-index:2}.progress-content[data-v-f1691f2e]{stroke-width:2px}.progress-content .top[data-v-f1691f2e]{z-index:1}
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">
   .vuejs-progress-bar[data-v-1c5cf8e4]{display:inline-block;-ms-flex-line-pack:stretch;align-content:stretch;width:0;line-height:20px}
  </style>
  <style data-emotion="">
  </style>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_humana.main_449" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/humana/main/prod/utag.449.js?utv=ut4.49.202304280130" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_humana.main_446" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/humana/main/prod/utag.446.js?utv=ut4.49.202304280130" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_humana.main_473" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/humana/main/prod/utag.473.js?utv=ut4.49.202208260148" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_humana.main_56" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/humana/main/prod/utag.56.js?utv=ut4.49.202303210132" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="utag_humana.main_7" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/humana/main/prod/utag.7.js?utv=ut4.49.202305030130" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="tiqapp" src="//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/tiqapp/utag.v.js?a=humana/main/202305030130&amp;cb=1683125216270" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="//solutions.invocacdn.com/js/networks/2230/1341883460/tag-live.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="true" charset="utf-8" crossorigin="anonymous" src="//gateway.foresee.com/code/6.8.1-mp/mpathy-modern.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script async="" charset="utf-8" id="tealium_visitor_service_7main_1" src="https://pc-humana-visitor-service-us-east-1.tealiumiq.com/humana/main/0187e21499f30018121a0d4d562c0506f004206700978?callback=utag.ut%5B%22writevamain%22%5D&amp;rnd=1683125217890" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <noscript>
   <strong>
    We're sorry but shopping for Humana plans doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.
   </strong>
  </noscript>
  <script nomodule="" src="./js/unsupported-browser.js">
  </script>
  <div data-v-63db0017="">
   <div data-v-63db0017="" id="skip">
    <a data-skip-link="" data-v-63db0017="" href="#main">
     Skip to content
    </a>
   </div>
   <header class="header" data-v-39385dc2="" data-v-63db0017="" data-vipr-header="" id="top">
    <div class="inner-wrapper" data-v-39385dc2="">
     <a data-humana-logo="" data-v-39385dc2="" href="https://www.humana.com">
      <img alt="Humana logo" class="bigh-icon" data-v-39385dc2="" src="/icons/bigh.svg"/>
      <img alt="Humana logo" class="humana-home-link" data-v-39385dc2="" src="/assets/logos/humana.svg"/>
     </a>
     <div class="contact-wrapper" data-v-39385dc2="">
      <div data-spanish-helper-button="" data-v-39385dc2="" data-v-6fbf9d02="">
       <a class="langLink spanish-link" data-href="es-plans.humana.com" data-lang="es" data-v-6fbf9d02="" href="//es-plans.humana.com" lang="es" mporgnav="">
        Espa�ol
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="ml-2" data-v-39385dc2="" data-v-62e714c5="">
       <button class="nb-btn nb-btn--secondary is-small" data-contact-us-button="" data-v-62e714c5="">
        <span class="contact-text" data-v-62e714c5="">
         Contact us
        </span>
        <span class="help-text" data-v-62e714c5="">
         Help
        </span>
       </button>
       <!-- -->
      </div>
      <!-- -->
     </div>
    </div>
   </header>
   <header class="sub-header" data-v-63db0017="" data-v-7a4b4f7b="" data-vipr-sub-header="">
    <!-- -->
   </header>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
   <main data-v-63db0017="" id="main">
    <!-- -->
    <div class="mb-4" data-other="" data-v-63db0017="">
     <section class="container h-100" data-v-63db0017="">
      <div class="core-loading-indicator-indeterminate-standard-wrapper" data-loading="" data-v-63db0017="" full-page="" style="">
       <!-- -->
       <div class="core-loading-indicator-indeterminate-standard-content">
        <div data-v-63db0017="" data-v-7e31268a="">
         <div class="zip-search wrapper" data-v-7e31268a="" data-zip-text="">
          <div class="col-1 mt-4 adjust-container-height" data-v-7e31268a="">
           <h1 class="pt-2 nb-h2" data-v-7e31268a="" tabindex="-1">
            Let us help you choose a plan
           </h1>
           <p class="mt-0" data-v-7e31268a="">
            In just a few simple steps, we can help you narrow down your choices based on what's most important to you.
      You may want to have a list of your doctors and current prescriptions handy before you get started.
            <br/>
            <br/>
            Enter your zip code below to see the Humana plans available in your area.
           </p>
           <form class="mt-5" data-v-037c6214="" data-v-7e31268a="">
            <div class="row" data-v-037c6214="" style="display: flex;">
             <div class="col" data-v-037c6214="">
              <div class="text-field-wrapper zip-input pb-4 hasContents" data-v-037c6214="" data-v-07a1902d="" data-zip-input="">
               <label data-v-07a1902d="" for="ZIP Code">
                ZIP Code
               </label>
               <div class="input-container" data-v-07a1902d="">
                <!-- -->
                <input aria-invalid="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="postal-code" autocorrect="off" data-mask-input="" data-v-07a1902d="" id="ZIP Code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required="required" spellcheck="false" type="text"/>
                <div class="style-wrapper" data-v-07a1902d="">
                </div>
               </div>
               <!-- -->
               <!-- -->
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col" data-v-037c6214="">
              <div class="dropdown-wrapper fips-input mb-4 active" data-counties="" data-v-037c6214="" data-v-c71dad74="">
               <label data-v-c71dad74="" for="select-county">
                Select county
               </label>
               <div data-toggle-dropdown="" data-v-c71dad74="">
                <div class="input-wrapper" data-v-c71dad74="">
                 <input data-v-c71dad74="" id="select-county"/>
                 <span data-v-c71dad74="">
                 </span>
                 <p class="fake-input" data-v-c71dad74="">
                 </p>
                </div>
                <div class="style-wrapper primary-border" data-v-c71dad74="">
                 <img alt="chevron down" data-v-c71dad74="" src="/icons/dropdown.svg"/>
                </div>
               </div>
               <ul class="list" data-dropdown-list="" data-v-c71dad74="">
                <li class="selected" data-dropdown-item="09003" data-v-c71dad74="">
                 Hartford, CT
                </li>
                <li class="" data-dropdown-item="09013" data-v-c71dad74="">
                 Tolland, CT
                </li>
               </ul>
               <!-- -->
              </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col btn-wrapper" data-v-037c6214="">
              <button class="nb-btn nb-btn--primary is-small mobile-btn" data-search-button="" data-v-037c6214="" disabled="disabled" type="submit">
               <span data-v-037c6214="">
                Get started
               </span>
               <!-- -->
              </button>
             </div>
            </div>
           </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 icon-wrapper" data-v-7e31268a="">
           <div class="svg-wrapper" data-v-7e31268a="">
            <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
            <svg class="" data-v-7e31268a="" focusable="false" id="Guides" role="presentation" style="" tabindex="-1" viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <defs>
              <style>
               .cls-1{fill:#f4f4f4;}.cls-2{fill:#fd98ab;}.cls-3{fill:#b0b1b1;}.cls-4{fill:#d8d8d8;}.cls-5{fill:#dedede;}.cls-6{fill:#d3d3d3;}.cls-7{fill:#aed879;}.cls-8{fill:#3a3b3d;}.cls-9{fill:#78be20;}.cls-10{fill:#66bbc4;}.cls-10,.cls-11,.cls-12{stroke:#3a3b3d;stroke-width:8px;}.cls-10,.cls-12{stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}.cls-11{stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-11,.cls-12{fill:none;}
              </style>
             </defs>
             <path class="cls-1" d="M471.68,570.77l-99.36-374.38c-1.79-6.76-8.73-10.79-15.49-8.99L71.46,263.13c-6.76,1.79-10.79,8.73-8.99,15.49l85.37,321.64,79.51,48.45,235.35-62.46c6.76-1.79,10.79-8.73,8.99-15.49Zm-154.15-222.07l-3.25,5.61-7.87,13.55-37.35,64.33-77.88-45.21-5.61-3.25c-21.51-12.49-28.82-40.04-16.34-61.55,12.49-21.51,40.04-28.82,61.55-16.34l5.61,3.25,3.25-5.61c12.49-21.51,40.04-28.82,61.55-16.34,21.51,12.49,28.82,40.04,16.34,61.55Z">
             </path>
             <path class="cls-2" d="M230.79,305.83l5.61,3.25,3.25-5.61c12.49-21.51,40.04-28.82,61.55-16.34,21.51,12.49,28.82,40.04,16.34,61.55l-3.25,5.61-7.87,13.55-37.35,64.33-77.88-45.21-5.61-3.25c-21.51-12.49-28.82-40.04-16.34-61.55,12.49-21.51,40.04-28.82,61.55-16.34Z">
             </path>
             <polygon class="cls-4" points="150.03 603.98 199.83 589.46 208.44 591.39 213.39 597.61 227.87 648.49 150.03 603.98">
             </polygon>
             <path class="cls-6" d="M277.01,379.79h460.94c4.53,0,8.21,3.68,8.21,8.21v314.41H268.81V387.99c0-4.53,3.68-8.21,8.21-8.21Z">
             </path>
             <rect class="cls-10" height="143.83" rx="12.99" ry="12.99" transform="translate(-242.93 825.91) rotate(-45)" width="48.39" x="851.29" y="634.28">
             </rect>
             <polyline class="cls-3" points="813.01 624.67 834.16 645.82 815.26 664.72 794.11 643.57">
             </polyline>
             <path class="cls-1" d="M719.99,407.27H294.98v272.47h54.25v-29.83c0-8.28,6.71-15,15-15h286.51c8.28,0,15,6.71,15,15v29.83h54.25V407.27Z">
             </path>
             <rect class="cls-1" height="272.47" width="425.01" x="294.98" y="407.27">
             </rect>
             <rect class="cls-9" height="62.17" rx="17.94" ry="17.94" width="316.5" x="349.23" y="476.56">
             </rect>
             <rect class="cls-7" height="62.17" rx="17.94" ry="17.94" width="316.5" x="349.23" y="553.76">
             </rect>
             <path class="cls-7" d="M665.73,661.35v-17.69c0-8.28-6.71-15-15-15H364.23c-8.28,0-15,6.71-15,15v17.69h316.5Z">
             </path>
             <circle class="cls-5" cx="714.69" cy="546.01" r="125.79">
             </circle>
             <path class="cls-9" d="M588.92,549.02h105.96c10.31,0,18.66-8.36,18.66-18.66v-46.29c0-10.31-8.36-18.66-18.66-18.66h-77.22s-29.41,48.53-28.75,83.62Z">
             </path>
             <path class="cls-11" d="M610.69,476.56h-246.46c-8.28,0-15,6.71-15,15v32.18c0,8.28,6.71,15,15,15h224.68">
             </path>
             <polygon class="cls-1" points="268.81 702.4 230.23 740.77 784.97 740.77 746.16 702.4 268.81 702.4">
             </polygon>
             <path class="cls-6" d="M231.56,740.77H783.68c4.33,0,7.84,3.51,7.84,7.84v7.41c0,9.37-7.61,16.98-16.98,16.98H240.09c-9.19,0-16.65-7.46-16.65-16.65v-7.46c0-4.48,3.64-8.12,8.12-8.12Z">
             </path>
             <circle class="cls-8" cx="507.48" cy="407.27" r="6.21">
             </circle>
             <path class="cls-12" d="M231.56,740.77H783.68c4.33,0,7.84,3.51,7.84,7.84v7.41c0,9.37-7.61,16.98-16.98,16.98H240.09c-9.19,0-16.65-7.46-16.65-16.65v-7.46c0-4.48,3.64-8.12,8.12-8.12Z">
             </path>
             <path class="cls-12" d="M746.16,409.65v-23.01c0-3.79-3.07-6.86-6.86-6.86H275.67c-3.79,0-6.86,3.07-6.86,6.86v315.75h477.36v-17.31">
             </path>
             <line class="cls-12" x1="227.28" x2="268.81" y1="740.77" y2="702.4">
             </line>
             <line class="cls-12" x1="787.69" x2="746.16" y1="740.77" y2="702.4">
             </line>
             <circle class="cls-12" cx="714.69" cy="546.01" r="125.79">
             </circle>
             <polyline class="cls-12" points="813.01 624.67 834.16 645.82 815.26 664.72 794.11 643.57">
             </polyline>
             <rect class="cls-12" height="143.83" rx="12.99" ry="12.99" transform="translate(-242.93 825.91) rotate(-45)" width="48.39" x="851.29" y="634.28">
             </rect>
             <line class="cls-12" x1="256.46" x2="185.14" y1="487.72" y2="506.64">
             </line>
             <line class="cls-12" x1="256.46" x2="194.77" y1="526.54" y2="542.92">
             </line>
             <line class="cls-12" x1="256.46" x2="220.32" y1="565.37" y2="574.96">
             </line>
             <path class="cls-12" d="M151.58,602.73l46.76-12.41c6.76-1.79,13.7,2.23,15.49,8.99l12.38,46.66">
             </path>
             <path class="cls-12" d="M255.15,641.7l-23.64,6.28c-2.88,.76-5.95,.35-8.52-1.15l-70.49-40.99c-2.57-1.5-4.44-3.95-5.21-6.82L62.36,279.01c-1.79-6.76,2.23-13.7,8.99-15.49l285.37-75.74c6.76-1.79,13.7,2.23,15.49,8.99l12.5,47.09,10.09,38.03,22.5,83.96">
             </path>
             <path class="cls-12" d="M255.52,424.32l-64.34-37.35-5.61-3.25c-21.51-12.49-28.82-40.04-16.34-61.55,12.49-21.51,40.04-28.82,61.55-16.34l5.61,3.25,3.25-5.61c12.49-21.51,40.04-28.82,61.55-16.34,21.51,12.49,28.82,40.04,16.34,61.55l-3.25,5.61-7.87,13.55">
             </path>
            </svg>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </section>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
   </main>
   <div data-v-63db0017="" data-vipr-footer="">
    <footer class="nc-footer">
     .
     .
     .
    </footer>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   var utag_data = {};
  </script>
  <script>
   (function(a,b,c,d) {
        a = config["TEALIUM_URL"];
        b = document;
        c = 'script';
        d = b.createElement(c);
        d.src = a;
        d.type = 'text/java'+c;
        d.async = true;
        a = b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];
        a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a);
      })();
  </script>
  <script async="" id="mpelid" src="//humanacom.mpeasylink.com/mpel/mpel.js">
  </script>
  <!-- // -->
  <script data-sitespect="true" type="text/javascript">
   <!--
  
      setTimeout(function() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(
          'GET',
          '/__ssobj/ard.png?7228967732447037654_1-899-'+(4664*360875+4210)+'&n=1',
          true
        );
        xhr.send();
      }, 500);
    
//-->
<!-- // -->
  </script>
  <div aria-atomic="true" aria-live="polite" class="nu-live-announcer nb-visually-hidden">
   Loading content...
  </div>
  <iframe class="aamIframeLoaded" id="destination_publishing_iframe_humanainc_0" name="destination_publishing_iframe_humanainc_0_name" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="https://humanainc.demdex.net/dest5.html?d_nsid=0#https%3A%2F%2Fplans.humana.com" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" title="Adobe ID Syncing iFrame">
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Few things to note:

1. You need to wait until the `Select county` dropdown appears on the webpage.
   `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.input-wrapper')))`
2. After Making sure it's already on the page, you can perform a `click` operation on it.
3. `soup.prettify()` itself return an `str`. So, there's no need to explicitly typecast it.

Answer (score 0):

when using beautifulsoup, it's good debugging that check the element in the browser. In this example, counties does not show up until click on `select-county` so first step would be click on it before making soup.

```
#click on select-country
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('select-county').click()")
```

then create a soup and filter out the values your are looking for, example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
counties=soup.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'list'}).find_all("li")
counties_list=[e_county.text for e_county in counties]
```

so result `counties_list` would be:

```
[' Hartford, CT ', ' Tolland, CT ']
```